# I am unable to compile and run a java program using python script

Tags: java, python

I think when I use `os.system("cd java path")` to change the path to java directory it's just don't change the path to that directory...
Here's the code I have written:

```
    import os
    import time
    #import subprocess
    os.system("cls")
    os.system("cd C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-13.0.1\\bin")
    time.sleep(2)
    os.system("javac add.java")
    os.system("java add")
```

Error:

> error: file not found: add.java
>       Usage: javac  
>       use --help for a list of possible options
>       Error: Could not find or load main class add
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: add

Comment: where is ubicated `add.java`? Your code only works if add.java is in the same folder as javac

Comment: You tried the `cd java path`, what do you think it suppose to do? It's not a command to add the directory to the PATH variable. Also, when you change the current directory (with `cd`), you can only access the files in that directory. So copy the `add.java` to the bin of java installation or use the absolute path to the `add.java` when calling `javac`. To avoid using absolute path you can firstly obtain the directory of `add.java` file, then use that variable before calling `javac`. The javac compiles to `cwd`, so calling `java add` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me and I had to copy script into the bin folder to make it work..

```
  import os
  import time
  aditya = True
  while aditya:
      os.system("cls")
      print("Enter a program name to execute:")
      name = input()
      os.system(f"javac {name}.java")
      os.system(f"java {name}")
      key = input()
```

Comment: I recomend you that you may have your programs out of installations folders. If later you install new java version, you will have to copy your codes and change the script

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that your current directory may not contains `add.java` after doing `cd C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-13.0.1\\bin`:
You may try this "static solution" that works for one java instalation:

```
import os
import time
#import subprocess
os.system("cls")
time.sleep(2)
os.system("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-13.0.1\\bin\\javac add.java")
os.system("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-13.0.1\\bin\\java add")
```

You may also include your java installation path in the PATH of the operative system, and you may run `javac` and `java` without their absolute path. If you later change the java version, with only updating the java path the script will maintain operable. In this case the code will be like this:

```
import os
import time
#import subprocess
os.system("cls")
time.sleep(2)
os.system("javac add.java")
os.system("java add")
```

Comment: Yeah It worked thanks! I also copied my script directly into my java folder and that worked too....

Comment: I'm happy to help you. Shame it costs me a downvote jajaja

Comment: If the asker says it worked, I can remove it. But IMO, it would be better to try adding that java folder to PATH instead of using absolute path, and as you see by asker comment - to explain why copying the java file to `\bin\` folder is bad. I'll be able to remove the -1 later (due to SO limits) or if you edit your answer.

Comment: @itwasntme I agree with you. I didn't take much effort in my answer. May be I just thinked in a fast question that works but doesn't really make a teach. Leave the -1 its ok. I think you can make a good answer from your asker comment

Comment: Mmm, I'd need to install python and etc. Just put some additional info in yours then I'll remove the -1. Your code works in the `cwd` where the program starts - so using it, there's no need to copy the `.java` file to the `bin`. I do it later, cause now I need to go to sleep for a bit.

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff I like your answer. It clarifies the problem and gives the right hint to a solution. And its smart and small ;)

Comment: The problem in question was comming from that `add.java` file didn't exist in `\bin\` dir. The solution in this question works, because the .java file was located in the directory where the python script is running. And TBH this solution is much better than copying .java file to bin dir. It would be good to mention about adding that bin dir to the enviromental PATH variable - so java\javac could be simply used as commands in terminal. @Eduardo, please edit your answer (simply with anything), so I could change my vode - I can't do it unless the answer is edited :(